# Jmeter Perfmon metrics collector-CPU utilization

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have collected performance metrics by using perfmon metrics collector 
In the graph it has plotted CPU against time
Is that CPU is in percentage???
Please clarify the unit of CPU metrics

And I tried to write the CPU utilization to a csv file, it has written the numbers in terms of 1000's how can I analyse???

[CPU metrics written in file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6wJV.png)

Can any one help me out please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you want to parse the values yourself - just divide them by 1000

   [image: PerfMon Metrics Collector]

   As you can see:

   - 1st sampler - 6% CPU
   - 2nd sampler - 36% CPU
   - 3rd sampler - 18% CPU
   - ...
2. You can always open JMeter GUI, add [PerfMon Metrics Collector listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon) and load existing results file using "Browse" button - the results file will be rendered in "Chart" panel
3. You can upload your file to [BM.Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/examples/489029/?utm_source=jpgc&utm_medium=wiki&utm_campaign=PerfMon#tab=tabMonitoring) analysis service and see the monitoring data in web interface